Does concentrating on a different spell end a concentration spell’s effect?
Some smite spells for paladins have additional on-going effects for a mob hit by them.
i.e wrathful smite causes a mob to be frightened until they succeed a wisdom save or until the spell ends. The spell duration is 1 minute and requires concentration.
If a paladins hits a creature with wrathful smite and it fails the initial wis save and becomes frightened,  and if the paladin then casts a different spell that requires concentration (like shield of faith) does this change what he is concentrating on, meaning the effects of wrathful smite ends straight away and the creature is no longer frightened as the spell has ended, or does the creature continue being frightened until the minute is over or until they pass a wis save?

@TreeSpawned This question acknowledges (correctly) that the spell has ended, so it can’t be a duplicate of a question that asks when the spell ends.

@ThomasMarkov This is such a simple, out of the book question, that I am sure we have a duplicate for this somewhere.

@TreeSpawned When a duplicate vote is cast, the question’s author is given the option to confirm the closure.

Related: If you're concentrating on one spell, and you cast another concentration spell, when exactly does the first spell end?. Might be a duplicate, but it assumes the first concentration spell ends when you cast the second one, while this one does not. If in doubt better leave it open, good dupes should be very obvious.

@Raj this question assumes the correct answer to that question and asks something else, so it can’t be a duplicate.

You might want to change the title, because the answer to that is "yes, that is what concentration is for". Your actual question is about spell effects, which may or may not end when the spell ends, as Kirt mentions in their comment on Markov's answer

The frightened effect ends when the spell ends, and the spell ends when you cast another concentration spell.
Wrathful smite states that the target is

frightened of you until the spell ends.

So when the spell ends, they stop being frightened, and if you stop concentrating, the spell ends immediately. Tasha’s Cauldron contains a helpful list of rules summaries, one of which explains succinctly the rules for concentration:

As soon as you start casting a spell or using a special ability that requires concentration, your concentration on another effect ends instantly

So casting a different spell that requires concentration will end the effects of wrathful smite immediately, and the target will no longer be frightened. The full rules, found in the PHB, reads:

The following factors can break concentration:

Casting another spell that requires concentration. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

[other stuff that ends concentration]




Great, clear answer.  Could be improved by acknowledging that some spells have effects that linger after the spell ends (eg Haste) and so it is necessary to check the description of wrathful smite, as you did.
